# PHP MySQL select field and increment the value

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-update, field

I want to get the value of specified field(it's INT) then increment this value and then update this in mysql. I tried this but it doesn't work. I'am completely green in MySQL.

```
            $attempts = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT attempts FROM employees WHERE lastname='$lastname'"));
            mysql_query("UPDATE employees SET attetmps='$attemtps++' WHERE lastname='$lastname'");
```

Comment: `UPDATE employees SET attempts=attempts + 1 WHERE lastname='$lastname'` would be better? you don't need select anymore

Comment: Doesn't work, nothing changed

Comment: *"I tried this but it doesn't work"* - Doesn't say much. You're not checking for errors and who knows which MySQL API you're using to connect with, and where your variables are coming from. So, it's anybody's "guess" at this point in time.

Comment: Im sorry about that, but i'am working online and mysql errors are disabled right now and i don't have a privilages to change it now and i have to finish  it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest: 
    `mysql_query("UPDATE employees SET attempts = attempts + 1 WHERE lastname = '".$lastname."'");`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use `mysql_fetch_array` you should know it returns an array and not one value

so try this

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT attempts FROM employees WHERE lastname='$lastname'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$attempts = $row['attempts'] + 1;
mysql_query("UPDATE employees SET attempts='$attempts' WHERE lastname='$lastname'");
?>
```

**or use one query.. you do not need to do two queries**

```
mysql_query("
    UPDATE employees
    SET attempts = attempts + 1
    WHERE lastname = '".$lastname."'
");
```

Comment: @paddyfields The OP did `SET attetmps='$attemtps++'` it's in their question. Not Mohammad's fault.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE employees SET attempts = attempts + 1 WHERE lastname = '$lastname'
```